# How to perform Zoom and onClick Action on Image View Using Android

Tags: android

I have a image view which is zoomed and when we zoom and click on image i want to get color of image how is it possible

Comment: How would zooming on an image and clicking be different from clicking without zooming?

Answer (score 0):

@Talha_Sheikh918 please check it,

Use this library this will help you to fulfill your requirements

**https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView**

use like this way

your_activity.xml

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

YourActivity.java

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

**Features**

- Out of the box zooming, using multi-touch and double-tap.
- Scrolling, with smooth scrolling fling.
- Works perfectly when used in a scrolling parent (such as ViewPager).
- Allows the application to be notified when the displayed Matrix has changed.
- Useful for when you need to update your UI based on the current zoom/scroll position.
- Allows the application to be notified when the user taps on the Photo.

**Edit**

If you want to get color of pointed pixel.

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        //the pixel data
        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);    

        return false;
        }
   });
```